# C ternary operator branches evaluation?

Tags: c, branch, conditional-operator, expression-evaluation

I always assumed the ternary operator in `C`  did not evaluate the branch that failed the test. Why does it in this case? `a` is less than `b` so only `c` should be assigned to `1`, `d` should remain `2`. Thank your for tips and suggestions. I have compiled with both gcc-9 and clang.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int a = 42;
  int b = 99;
  int c = 0;
  int d = 2;

  // Both branches are evaluated?
  a < b ? c, c = 1 : d, d = 1;

  printf("c %d, d %d.\n", c, d);
  // Prints c 1, d 1.
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the comma expression there?

Comment: Because otherwise the compiler gives me an error `lvalue required as left operand of assignment` which I am still investigating (at least one of the commas has to stay).

Comment: Which turned out to be another matter of operator precedence. Putting parens around it fixed it. `a < b ? c = 1 : (d = 1);`

Comment: That you need to jump through so many hoops to get it right is a clear indicator that the conditional expression isn't really the best solution here. Why not a plain `if else` statement? Which is more readable, clearer, more maintainable, and much harder to get wrong.

Comment: You are right, I was doing an exercise and wanted to see if it was possible and got stuck into this precedence problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma operator has lower precedence than the conditional operator, so your expression is equivalent to:

```
(a < b ? c, c = 1 : d), d = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! It was so simple.

Comment: And the conditional operator has different precedence in C++, so beware.